# Bulk release removal in TFS2017

Tags: tfs, release-management

I have been removing unused releases in TFS 2017, due some of them were created automatically and never used. but this task is monkey job. I would like to perform a bulk deletion, or create an script to delete them.

So far, I was checking the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/overview)  but there is no option to abandon or to delete the releases.

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, you can use the REST API to abandon or delete the release.

[**Abandoning an active release**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#abandoning-an-active-release): (Mentioned in the official document)

```
PATCH http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/LCTFVCScrum/_apis/Release/releases/10?api-version=3.1-preview

{
  "status": "abandoned",
  "manualEnvironments": null,
  "comment": "Abandon the release"
}
```

**Delete the release:** (Not mentioned in the official document, tracked with the [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool )

```
DELETE http://win-server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/LCTFVCScrum/_apis/Release/releases/9?api-version=3.1-preview
```

Both of them work well.

So, you can get the release list first using REST API (to get the release IDs), then create a script to delete the releases with the `Release IDs` which you want to be deleted.

Get release list:

```
GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/LCTFVCScrum/_apis/Release/releases
```